# How to develop shopify payment plugins and integration with shopify hosted solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am new to the Shopify. I have some idea about Shopify e-commerce
Which is developed in Ruby on Rails that I know but I don't have  idea to how to start up with Shopify payment plugin and how to execute and test with our local code.
Please if you have any experienced with Shopify plugin development please share your idea here. I will be very thankful to you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Shopify uses active merchant gem to do process payments. You could write a gem which uses active merchant to implement a payment gateway. And then ask Shopify to approve it. Though it might not be a quick solution. The alternative is to implement an offline payment system. More details https://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/payments/payment-gateway#other-ways-to-pay.

Comment: Hello Troy SK 

Thanks for your reply.
How to start implement an offline payment system in Shopify ?
Please if you have knowledge then share with me.
Thank you

Comment: Have you gone through the link shared? It details that.

Comment: Hello Troy SK Thanks for the reply
I have started ruby on rails learning and I gone through your link.
I have checkout this repositry and started to developing.
https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/wiki/contributing
But can you give me idea how to test it from my local server.

Comment: You'll have to fake the payment gateway response or do real transactions. The getting started guide has some details https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/wiki/Getting-Started. You might want to look into the implementation of existing integrations.